# C# Load two fonts

Tags: c#

I have this code for loading custom font from resources:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Text;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadFonts();    
}
PrivateFontCollection LoadFont = new PrivateFontCollection();

    private void LoadFonts()
    {
        Stream fontStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("embedded_font.osb.ttf");
        System.IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)fontStream.Length);
        byte[] fontdata = new byte[fontStream.Length];
        fontStream.Read(fontdata, 0, (int)fontStream.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(fontdata, 0, data, (int)fontStream.Length);
        LoadFont.AddMemoryFont(data, (int)fontStream.Length);
        fontStream.Close();
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(data);
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Font = new Font(LoadFont.Families[0], 9, FontStyle.Bold);
        label1.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
    }
```

It's ok, works nice, but I wan't to load two fonts. Now i'm trying to make it with two same codes, with other variables, but i think is not an original answer to my question. How can I do it? For example I have **osb.ttf** (Open Sans Bold) and **os.ttf** (Open Sans). What's next? 
I wan't to

```
label1.Font = new Font(LoadFont.Families[0], 9, FontStyle.Bold);
label1.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;

label2.Font = new Font(LoadFont.Families[1], 9);
label2.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
```

etc... How to do it?

Thanks in advace

Comment: Obviously you just do the thing you're doing now but twice.